# Banshee - Can't delete album artwork

Tags: banshee, artwork

- Banshee 2.6.2
- Xubuntu 14.04

I can't delete some album cover pictures/artworks for some reason. After I right-click on a track, then right-click on the picture and click on `Delete this cover` it reappears roughly 3 seconds later.

It might have to do with the mp3 files being from a buddy's PC. Does anyone have any pointers how I can get Banshee to download the right covers? Or at least not the same wrong one?

Comment: Is there a `cover.jpg` or something similar in the album folder?

Comment: @texasflood Yes, the original album cover was there, I think.

Comment: Try deleting that and see if the problem goes away? I think banshee uses it to regenerate the cover art

Comment: @texasflood It did not help. Seems like Banshee re-downloaded it or had stored the image file somewhere else as well. But this was over half a year ago and so far I have evaded the issue by deleting the album tag. Not that I used the album info much in the first place.

Comment: Rename the ~/.cache/media-art/ folder, this should make banshee rescan for the cover art